# WiFi connects, but pages don't load

Tags: networking, wireless

This problem is tied to one WiFi network only. I tested it using System Monitor's data activity measurement. After connecting, there is about 40 seconds of working connection, then it linearly decreases to almost zero within about 20 seconds, then there is a big spike in activity, then it goes dead. The computer is still ostensibly connected, but it claims signal strength is 0%. I tried "ping google.com":

```
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

All other devices connect to this WiFi without problems. When I create a WiFi bridge through my phone and connect to that, it works normally. The WiFi had previously worked fine for many months. I don't recall any particular change I could link to the problem.

All network issues I found on Ask Ubuntu were "unable to connect to network" problems, but my computer stays connected the entire time. The WiFi just eventually stops transmitting any information.

I had Ubuntu 18.04 and upgraded to 20.04. The problem persists.

**EDIT**: In response to johncli:

1:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

etc.

Is the rest of your answer applicable in this situation?

3: The file clearly cannot be edited by hand:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search home
```

The output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp3s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a8:1e:84:81:4b:4e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 18233  bytes 1725789 (1.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 18233  bytes 1725789 (1.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.136  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::fbeb:d153:68ac:c2f1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:a0:67:af:bb:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1161729  bytes 1493982625 (1.4 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 600  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 470115  bytes 91019517 (91.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The output of `route -n`:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref        Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0            0 wlp2s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0            0 wlp2s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0            0 wlp2s0
```

I checked [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/193941/953305). It delays the problems for a while, but they reappear after half an hour or so. If it is any use, the log shows, several times,

```
Server returned error NXDOMAIN, mitigating potential DNS violation DVE-2018-0001, retrying transaction with reduced feature level UDP.
```

**Edit 2: Reply to William Martens**:

The output of `sudo service network-manager status`:

```
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-10-08 17:44:44 CEST; 20h ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 35927 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 9322)
     Memory: 7.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─35927 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9406] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9406] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9406] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9406] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9406] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9407] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9407] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9407] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option routers              => '192.168.0.1'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9407] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.255.0'
říj 09 14:15:48 matej-Aspire-E5-575 NetworkManager[35927]: <info>  [1602245748.9407] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed extended -> extended
```

(`říj` would presumably be `oct` in English)

**EDIT 3**:

There is nothing I did with any wireless settings that directly preceded this. All the answers to similar questions are either diagnostics or shots in the dark. The ones that seem to have worked are all restarts, but it isn't clear how the problem originated.

Similar questions with no good answers:

[Wifi connected but no data transfer: "ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193264/wifi-connected-but-no-data-transfer-ping-sendmsg-no-buffer-space-available)

[wifi connected but no internet, is this the end?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279329/wifi-connected-but-no-internet-is-this-the-end?rq=1)

[Connected to wifi, but quits loading pages after a random amount of time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228475/connected-to-wifi-but-quits-loading-pages-after-a-random-amount-of-time?rq=1)

[wifi doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04 after a short time until I restart the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/608423/wifi-doesnt-work-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-a-short-time-until-i-restart-the-system?rq=1)

[WiFi problem with hp probook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675581/wifi-problem-with-hp-probook) (commands provided with no explanation return Error 404)

[Wifi connected but no internet access (Lubuntu 14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715724/wifi-connected-but-no-internet-access-lubuntu-14-04?rq=1)

[Wifi apparently connected, but webpages won't load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659507/wifi-apparently-connected-but-webpages-wont-load)

Comment: well then you have another or other problem, before even having the DNS problem, i found this topic with many solutions to "sendmsg error" please check that out <https://askubuntu.com/questions/210451/what-does-ping-sendmsg-no-buffer-space-available-mean> - after solving that sendmsg try to repeat the stages on my answer to fix the issue.

Comment: if you solved the first problem with the "sendmsg" you can edit the resolv.conf file as i wrote on my answer, it should fix the problem, also you can try and delete the "search home" + do the ip change that recommended on the answer, then keep follow the answer steps.

Comment: @johncli What is the "proper" way to edit the nameserver?

Comment: your DNS server, it means when you are asking for DNS request go to X server, if it is configure as localhost its sending the DNS request through your gateway and then it depends on your gateway DNS configuration.

Comment: @johncli What I meant was that since the file cannot be edited by hand, what is the process to changing the nameserver?

Comment: please use the following commands `cd /etc/` then `ls -l | grep resolv.conf|` and print the output of that command, maybe we have to make change at the file owner and permissions parameters.

Comment: @Kotlopou Hello! I got 1 suggestion, It cannot be something related to wpa_supplicant? or some conflicts with something(services maybe breaking something, or each other - maybe making a deadlock?), Or: Maybe it is  Restricted-Bandwidth?  Sorry these things just came to mind,  Got the ideas from a post from raspberry pi:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94178/wifi-wont-start because  I had the same problem as you while I was doing a project in Raspberry Pi (awhile ago)     1 NOTE:  SORRY if this is completely, Downright  crazy/unrelated, I'm just trying to help; //Best wishes

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to `ping 8.8.8.8` or any other ip to check internet access.

   - you can ping any other public address that is "up" for sure
2. If the ping success then you have internet and the problem is on DNS configuration.
3. Exec the command `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`.
4. It is probably sets on "nameserver" as localhost ip (127.0.0.53).
5. If it is on 127.0.0.53 change the address to 1.1.1.1 or 8.8.8.8.

   - you can change the address to any good Domain Name Server.
   - i am using 1.1.1.1 as my favorite.
6. Save the resolv.conf file.
7. Exec the command `sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`
8. Try to ping a domain address like google.com or just open the web and surf to a website to check if the change helped out.
9. **Please comment the output or the settings that you find out for we can solve the issue togther**.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer over at https://askubuntu.com/questions/193264/wifi-connected-but-no-data-transfer-ping-sendmsg-no-buffer-space-available, and it seems to be working so far. I'll edit the question by tomorrow if it turns out to work.

Comment: no problem, please keep update about the status, and we will solve that issue together.

Comment: It seems that the problem just gets delayed by half an hour or so. Maybe it is just the extended buffer. I couldn't find the proper way to edit the nameserver.

Comment: have you used root permissions ?

Comment: With which command?

Comment: to change the nameserver on resolv.conf, and please add the output of `ifconfig` and `route -n` to your answer ;), if you are online ill be glad to try and help you live through the chat.

Comment: I edited that into the question. I did use sudo when looking into the resolv.conf file, but that seems irrelevant since I didn't edit it. I could go into chat tomorrow, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

---

If you haven't already, try this:

```
sudo service networking stop
sudo service networking start
sudo service networking reload

sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
sudo service network-manager reload
```

If you have Ethernet (working, that is)
Connect to ethernet and:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

**If you have net-tools installed: **

```
sudo apt remove net-tools
sudo apt install net-tools
```

**If you do not have net-tools installed**

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

---

**EDIT:**

---

### Can you try the answer from here? It's **exactly the same problem**

[Wifi apparently connected, but webpages won't load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659507/wifi-apparently-connected-but-webpages-wont-load)

And, if possible: can you try to run the diagnostic tool they are mentioning in the post?

> " I found a thread that used a diagnostic tool (wireless-info on
> github), which might help you guys figure out if there's anything
> wrong with my current system/drivers. "

---

---

+**EDIT** 3:

**original link**
[WiFi disconnects for few seconds and resumes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730908/wifi-disconnects-for-few-seconds-and-resumes?noredirect=1&lq=1)

These lines, according to the problem you're facing, is in my opinion quite interesting: **(I changed it slightly,** look on the **original link**)  **But, I can't stress this enough; what I skipped is what I thought was not going to work, which is why I suggest you reading the link, with the original answer!**

install or reinstall wpa_supplicant

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install wpasupplicant
```

**upgrade and** install build-essential and linux-headers

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

and

```
sudo ifdown wlan0
sudo ifup wlan0
```

You can reboot

---

---

Small questions that could be worth looking into:

- You don't have any **VPN** software installed, that is blocking it /disrupting ?
  I thought of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/278247/macbook-pro-on-any-wifi-stays-connected-but-wont-load-pages-after-a-few-minutes
- You haven't used **macchanger**? (or, supplied wrong mac - or anything like that?)
  I thought of this from here;  [Ubuntu shows that it's connected to wifi, but will not load any pages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/786469/ubuntu-shows-that-its-connected-to-wifi-but-will-not-load-any-pages)
- You have not tried something with airmon?  from here: https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng

**Killing interfering processes**

**This command stops network managers then kill interfering processes left:**

```
~# airmon-ng check kill
Killing these processes:

  PID Name
  870 dhclient
 1115 wpa_supplicant
```

---

Hope this can be useful!
Good luck;

Regards.

Comment: This seems to have solved the problem (I'll see for real by tomorrow), but still hasn't explained it... +1, but no bounty.

Comment: @Kotlopou Hello! First things first: I'm so glad (hopefully it did!) begun working, and no I know  I have not explained in my answer, I just wanted to help - and solve the issue/problem, have a great day!  hope this solved it.

Comment: @Kotlopou I could try to explain, (In my answer)  but then I would need the  status of the services networking and network-manager;  for example: sudo service network-manager status

Comment: One day later, still seems to work. Would network manager status still be useful (since it works now and the problem trace is presumably gone)?

Comment: @Kotlopou  I'm so glad I could be of help!  Yeah I mean, I said I could try to explain if I had that output,  but - I'm happy it got solved!  //Best Wishes!

Comment: The problem reappeared and was solvable by the same procedure. I got the status report and edited it into the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113921/discussion-between-kotlopou-and-william-martens).

Comment: @Kotlopou Sorry to comment here again; but I have edited my answer, what I provided is something really interesting, it's the same problem.  (note this may not fix your problem, but worth a try)

Comment: My problem seems to be fixed again, though at this point it is hard to say how. I'll edit the question a bit with some specifics.