# Internet connection not working on Foxit Reader (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, foxitreader

I am using **Ubuntu 18.04** on **Dell Vostro 15 - 3546**.

```
uname -a

Linux <device-name> 4.15.0-118-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 8 12:30:01 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have recently installed Foxit Reader following [this post](https://websiteforstudents.com/how-to-install-foxit-reader-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04-desktop/). In Foxit Reader internet doesn't seem to work.
When I open Foxit Drive I get the following network error:

[image: network error in Foxit Reader]

When I click on the `Check for updates` button the progress bar doesn't move at all :

[image: No progress while checking for updates]

Output of `ethtool eth0`:

```
Settings for eth0:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Supported FEC modes: Not reported
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
    Speed: 10Mb/s
    Duplex: Half
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 0
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    Current message level: 0x00000033 (51)
                   drv probe ifdown ifup
    Link detected: no
```

**EDIT:**
FYI, this is not a Virtual Machine, no VPN software is being used.
Output of `ifconfig`:

```
eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:2a:72:ca:ab:6e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 41  base 0xd000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 12386  bytes 847387 (847.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 12386  bytes 847387 (847.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.30  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        ether b0:10:41:18:23:11  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 133014  bytes 70779214 (70.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 49151  bytes 10707681 (10.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Well, I think you really have a problem in your network according to the line that says: `Speed: 10Mb/s` Really you have a switch at 10Mb/s? (kidding) Or maybe a damaged cable? Also it says: `Link detected: no` That means the cable is not connected. It should say something like: `Speed: 1000Mb/s Duplex: Full ... Link detected: yes` Please, paste the results of: `ifconfig` Are you using VPN Software? is this a Virtual Machine? Cheers.

Comment: Looks like OP is using wireless... not sure what the `ethtool` output was for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is not related to your network settings at all.

Some time ago, Foxit retired the Foxit Drive service.  Multiple websites report that there was a notice some time ago that the Drive service and plugin in Foxit would be retired and should not be used.

What that windows is reporting is the Foxit Drive plugin says you have no network connection, when in **reality** the problem is that Foxit Drive is just dead and gone and no longer available upstream.  The corresponding Foxit Drive plugin is the problem and is still present in this third-party binary.

Unfortunately, there's no way to *disable* the Foxit Drive plugin, nor is there a way for us or anyone else to fix the problem.  You need to open a ticket with Foxit to tell them to remove the Foxit Drive plugin.  Until they release an update that removes Foxit Drive from the equation, it will still continue to give you those errors.  Basically, don't use the Drive plugins at all or try to use Foxit Drive which is dead.

Comment: Also FYI: Linux variant of Foxit is ANCIENT and they no longer update it.  Consider using a different PDF reader software.

Answer (score 1):

Copying from my other answer, over here:

[WiFi connects, but pages don't load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278694/wifi-connects-but-pages-dont-load)

If you haven't already, try this:

```
sudo service networking stop
sudo service networking start
sudo service networking reload

sudo service network-manager stop
sudo service network-manager start
sudo service network-manager reload
```

If you have Ethernet (working, that is) Connect to ethernet and:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

**If you have net-tools installed:**

```
sudo apt remove net-tools
sudo apt install net-tools
```

If you do not have net-tools installed

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

And, I would reboot after this. Hope this can be useful!

Edit:  It cannot be something related to MTU?
[How to change MTU without ifconfig in ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281190/how-to-change-mtu-without-ifconfig-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Good luck;

Regards.

Comment: Make sure FoxitReader have net access. Not blocked by a firewall e.g ufw, or something else.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it didn't work.