# How to change MTU without ifconfig in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, ethernet, ifconfig

I need to change the `MTU` size in my newly installed ubuntu 18.04. This can be done with `ifconfig`.
But i can not install `ifconfig`. Whenever i run command `sudo apt install net-tools` i get the following errors.

```
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 net-tools amd64 1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60+git20161116.90da8a0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Then i tried `sudo apt-get update` and got the following

```
asif@asif-HP:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                        
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                               
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease            
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
Err:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
Reading package lists... Done           
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Actually i am trying change MTU size to solve the problem `Could not resolve 'archive.canonical.com'` so im kind of in deadlock. What do i do now?

N.B: I changed ubuntu archive server but always same error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# ip link set dev eth0 mtu 1400
```

I take it from [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-can-i-setup-the-mtu-for-my-network-interface/)
But are you sure that is the solution to your problem ?

Comment: Well i had to add google dns , but this solved my "can not access some websites" problem

Comment: indeed as I know you have to change the mtu in some strange lan. Maybe when you have enabled Jumbo Frame in lan ---> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame

Answer (score 1):

To change MTU in GUI:  go to network settings -> click the preferred Network interface > there you can change MTU

[image]

Comment: Edit: seems trivial maybe but; make sure you are connected to the internet..